# $A \in \mathcal{B}$ iff $1_{A} \in \mathcal{B}$

Tags: probability-theory, solution-verification

I need help with one part of this proof.

In the measurable space $(\Omega,\mathcal{B})$, show $A \in \mathcal{B}$ iff $1_{A} \in \mathcal{B}$.

If I suppose that $1_{A} \in \mathcal{B}$, then

$$A=1_{A}^{-1}\{1\} \in \mathcal{B},$$

hence $A \in \mathcal{B}$.

Is this right?

On the other hand, I got lost with the other part. In fact, I'm confused about what does it mean that $1_{A} \in \mathcal{B}$?

Any help?

Comment: I'm guessing that what they really mean is show that $A\in\mathcal{B}$ if and only if the function $1_A$ is $\mathcal{B}$-measurable.

Comment: $\in$ is defied as a binary relation between sets, but $1_A$ is a function, I think you may be making a typing error or miss-understanding a shorthand.

Comment: @NickPeterson yes, I think I can see it clearer. Then that means that $1_{A}^{-1}\{I\} \in \mathcal{B}$, but I cannot see for what I?

Comment: To show measurability, you need to start from any measurable subset of $\mathbb{R}$.  However, you can quickly break into cases based on the two key questions: is $0$ in the subset, and is $1$ in the subset?

Comment: Let me see. So I have different cases like I=[0,1], then $1_{A}^{-1}\{I\}=\Omega \in \mathcal{B}$ or if $I=[0,1)$, then $1_{A}^{-1}\{I\}=A^c \in \mathcal{B}$ and so on? I think this is true because we have a $\sigma$-algebra.

Comment: I dont know if $I=[0,1]$ its correct